# The 'iCloud' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

I am add iCloud in My Application but give error "The 'iCloud' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit  https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll." in Device. In simulator run perfectly. How to remove iCloud from application? I am tired test my application on iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling the "iCloud" capability from your target. In Xcode, navigate to your target, then tap the "Capabilities" tab, and turn the "iCloud" switch to "Off".